# Check? Confirmation? Verification?

Tags: word-choice

I am developing a piece of software which shows a verification message when the user does something. For example he wants to do something and the message says (the pattern is decided as in Title, Message, Buttons, can't change it)

Check

The system will do this. Agree?

[yes][no]

Somehow I am not comfortable with the word "Check". As native speakers do you think I should go for say "Confirmation" or "Verification"... or should I just let "Check" there... what do you feel?

Answer (score 2):

To me, a native English speaker this reads a little oddly. One part of the problem is that it feels brusque, treating the user as someone to be controlled. Another issue is that **Check** is a little ambiguous

> The system wants to check that it should perform the action

or

> Please will the user verify that the action to be performed is correct

Are you limited to a single word where **Check** appears? The pattern I see in some systems is

> Action XYZ will be taken
>
> Please confirm
>
> [Action XYZ] / [Cancel]

Note the separation of the proposed action and the request for confirmation and the buttons being labelled with instructions to the system.

Example:

> File wibble.doc will be overwritten.
>
> A file of that name already exists in this folder, it will be over-written. Do you wish to replace this file?
>
> Replace / Cancel

If you are limited to a single word in the first line then I would not use the word **Check**, this can sound like a command to the user.

> Check (right now, be precise, do you know what you're doing?)

Instead, perhaps a label for the phase of interaction we're in. This is a step confirming an action or verifying an instruction.

> Confirmation
>
> Saving wibble.doc. A file of that name already exists in this folder, it will be over-written. Do you wish to replace this file?
>
> Replace / Cancel